# How to use I2C slave EEPROM backend

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I have a raspberry pi3 and a working board. I'd like one as a i2c master(pi3), and another one is slave(working board).
I'd like to read/write to working board from pi3.

I found it on the Internet.
https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-i2c/msg30208.html

Following this steps.
I set CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE=y, CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE_EEPROM=y and CONFIG_I2C_CHARDEV=y to kernel of my working board, and set

```
# echo slave-24c02 0x1064 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device
[  233.396818] i2c i2c-5: new_device: Instantiated device slave-24c02 at 0x64
#
```

I ran the i2cdetect.
I can see the 0x64 device from my working board, but my pi3 can not see it.

```
(working board)# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

```
(p3)# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I just connect SDA1 and SCL1 to working board from pi3.

How to fix it?

my pi3
kerenl: 4.19.97-v8(buildroot-2020.02.8)

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out the problem? I'm writing a kernel driver for a custom device and have a similar issue. The slave backend never registers to the i2c driver as slave when I run `new_device`

Comment: I am not sure I fixed it. In my case, I used linux kernel I2C slave module. I found a solution to fix my issue. I must not use i2cdetect command on my pi3 and then it works.